# pt-SO ads are outdated

Tags: bug, status-completed, advertising, portuguese-stack-overflow

There is something that is annoying me for some time: the Portuguese Stack Overflow [is not in beta anymore](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/06/stack-overflow-in-portuguese-now-with-less-beta/) and we already had two SO logo updates, but the ads were not updated. Also, the phrase "Aberto ao público", which means "Open to the public" makes no sense anymore.

I know that the SO team [deeply cares about the quality of the ads](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2016/02/why-stack-overflow-doesnt-care-about-ad-blockers/) that are displayed. Maybe it's time to update these ads logos?

[image: pic1]
[image: pic2]
[image: pic3]

I've tried the ad feedback tool, but when I've clicked in the option "Other", it dismissed the ad without allowing me to explain what is the ad problem.

[image: feedback]

Comment: This should probably be on [its Meta site](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @D-side, I don't think so. These ads appear only at main SO. The pt-SO community won't see them.

Comment: Well reported @Zanon!

Comment: As a case in point, at ru.SO [we discuss ads in **its** Meta](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2467/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80-ru-so). Not that I mind this being here, I just think it would get a faster response that way, there probably being more people dedicated to **that** community. It's up to the moderators, of course :)

Comment: I let Gabe know. He'll either see that the current ads are fixed, or (possibly) take the opportunity to try some new creatives. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

That sinking feeling you get when you know you've forgotten something but can't quite put your finger on what it might be ..

We'll get these fixed soon-ish, but continue to leave them in rotation until we do because even while antiquated, they do a great job of pointing out that we have SO in Portuguese to those that would likely be interested.

Thanks for letting us know!

**Update:**

New creatives are now in rotation, and we'll continue to update them so that folks aren't seeing the same ads all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Whew!

Thank you for spotting this. The ads in question are now out of rotation. I hope to have properly-sized sidebars live soon, as well.

Keep up the good work, and thank you again!

Comment: Stevvvve, I'm still seeing them right now. I don't mind, it is a very minor issue, but it seems that it was not fixed yet. Another point is: I agree with [Tim](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317381/1476885) that it's better to keep them outdated than to remove them, since they have an important role to increase the pt-SO community.

Comment: @Zanon Blerg. In my rush to take care of this, I only axed the ones that have 'beta' on them; not all of the ones with the old logos. When these are all updated, I'll update my answer. Thank you for keeping any eye out!

Comment: Stevvve, minor issue, but they're still there. Could you please edit the question to remove the [status-completed]?

Comment: @Zanon Got it. Will do. Been waiting on new creative for a while now. Hope to have perty new ads for you soon.