# Is "Please, don't show this ad again" button cookie-based? Could it be user-related?

Tags: support, advertising

Two days ago, I've commented that [pt-SO ads are outdated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317328/pt-so-ads-are-outdated). I really like them, but while I was trying to warn SE-employees about this small issue, I've used the ad feedback tool:

[image: feedback]

and clicked on "Other", hoping to explain the problem with a text box (but there is none):

[image: feedback]

Since the tool says **"We won't show you that ad again"**, I thought that I would never see it again, but two days later, it came back:

[image: ad]

It makes me wonder: when someone clicks on "please, hide this ad", you set this info in a cookie to prevent this ad to show again? Or you blacklist the ad for the user's IP? Or you just hide it during the current session? What is the mechanism?

Since I've changed my PC and IP, that's why I'm seeing the same ad again, right? I really don't mind. I'm just *suggesting* that it would be better to set this info in the user's data and fallback to cookies/IP if the user is anonymous. Is it possible?

Comment: *We* don't do anything. Those ads are served by Adzerk, and whatever methods they use in regards to preventing ads from appearing for the same user again, we have no control over.

Comment: That seems like an intelligent business model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As animuson said, that functionality is done through AdZerk, and they use cookies. It's possible that long-term we'll be able to use your Account ID to permanently store your settings if you're logged in, but not anytime soon.

Comment: Please also note that when you decline to see an ad again, it is specific to that targeted placement in the ad server. If the ad is also running in a different placement, you may see the ad again and need to opt out again.